# In MVC modeling, how do I bind a property to another model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

So I have 2 models, where Model2 is linked to Model1:

```
public class Model1 {
    public int model1ID { get; set; }
    public int model2ID { get; set; }
}
public class Model2 {
    public int model2ID { get; set; }
    public int someData { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to do this:

```
public class Model1 {
    public int model1ID { get; set; }
    public Model2 model2 { get; set; }
}
```

So I can do this:

```
        var linqTest = (
            from curTest in database.Model1s
            select curTest 
        ).Sum(curTest => curTest .model2.someData);
```

EDIT:

My problem is that how do I tell c# how to load the "model2" property using "model2ID"?  The specific error I get is:

```
{"Invalid column name 'model1_ID'.\r\n Invalid column name 'model1_ID'."}
```

Notice that I don't have any property with the name model1_ID.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM, no, I am not using entity framework.

Comment: You bind to model data to the view, not models to models.  If you want to aggregate a model within a model, you can do what you've detailed.  Are you having problems doing that, or is there a specific question?

Comment: @PeterRitchie, I guess my problem is that how does the model know how to load my property "model2" in "Model1"?

Comment: @YongkeBillYu How does your model "load" the other properties like `model1ID`?

Comment: I guess it load it automatically because there is a column in the database named "model1ID", but there certainly isn't a column in the database named "model2" with a type of "Model2".  There is only a column called "model2ID" with a type of int.

Comment: What ORM are you using?

Comment: When you say "Load", do you mean loaded from the database or loaded in a postback via MVC Model Binding?

Comment: Ok, it turn out I am using Entity Framework and what I was looking for was the syntax to using "association properties", which in my example, I had to add "model2ID" as a property extra property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use association properties: 
Entity Framework association properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx

Linq to SQL association properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629295.aspx

Your data model with association properties will look something like:

```
public class Model1 
{
    public int model1ID { get; set; }
    public int model2ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Model2 model2 { get; set; }
}

public class Model2
{
    public int model2ID { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't want to use association properties, you can use a join in your query:

```
var linqTest = (
            from mod1 in database.Model1s
            join mod2 in database.Model2s
                on mod1.model2ID equals mod2.model2ID
            select new { Mod1 = mod1, Mod2 = mod2 } 
        ).Sum(row => row.Mod2.someData);
```

Check the link @nercan posted for more information on joins in Linq queries

Comment: You are completely correct.  This is an associative property and I just had to add the "model2ID" property to my model to make it work.